# Can i edit image created in jupyter notebook without re running

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I plotted an image in jupyter notebook, and instead of 'loss' I typed 'accuracy' in the image title and saved it in 'svg' format, and notebook is saved in github repo. 
I want to know is there any way to edit it the image, without running the whole script again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re-run the part of code for printing/saving that image only in the new cell in the same jupyter file if you haven't closed that file yet